# Is there a way to eliminate the owner and group from `ls -l`?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I never need to see the owner and group for the files listed with `ls -l` (actually, `ls -laF`) and am wondering if there's a way to remove them from the output. So I want to change this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 chuck  staff  45 Jul  2 23:29 directory@ -> /Users/chuck/Projects/directory
```

into this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 45 Jul  2 23:29 directory@ -> /Users/chuck/Projects/directory
```

I'm using bash under OS X, but I would assume the answer would apply to any Unix-y OS, such as the Debian machine that runs my web server.

Comment: You can leave out the group by using `-o` instead of `-l`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the the `-g` and `-o` options for `ls`. For example:

```
user@host:~ # ls -go
total 0
drwx------+ 35   1190 Jul  2 18:24 Desktop
drwx------+ 78   2652 Jun 29 16:21 Documents
drwx------+ 11    374 Jul  2 11:05 Downloads
drwx------@ 70   2380 Mar 27 11:22 Library
drwx------+  6    204 Jun  2 20:00 Movies
drwxr-xr-x+  8    272 Oct 21  2013 Music
drwx------+  6    204 Jul  2 10:58 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  6    204 Jul  5  2013 Public
drwxr-xr-x+  4    136 May 29 14:52 Sites
```

There are a good number of options available to modify the output of `/bin/ls` which can be found in the utility's `man` page. Learning to read `man` pages can take a little bit of practice (and this is certainly the case for the more esoteric and deeper components of the OS). I would consider `ls`' page a great starting point. It's about a approachable as they come. Type at the command prompt `man ls` and dip your toes in to the deep waters. It's not so cold.

Comment: I actually did read `man ls`, but misunderstood what I was reading. It says `-g` will *display* the group name and that `-o` will omit the group *id*. Honestly, I'm more confused about this particular man page, but I'm happy it works. :)

Comment: In the version from `(GNU coreutils) 8.21` man ls resport
`-g     like -l, but do not list owner` and `-o     like -l, but do not list group information` :-) System you go man that you find ;-)